# Intel Turbo Boost parameter in bios crashes the system

Tags: processor

I recently built a computer with these components:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte Z790 GAMING X AX
- Processor: i7-13700KF
- Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080, 10 GB
- RAM: HyperX DDR5 2x16GB 5200
- PSU: Thermaltake 850W
- CPU cooling: MSI MAG CORELIQUID C360

After the first build I went straight into bios, enabled XMP profile on 5200 and exited it. Windows started normally, went to test in random games, all started and immediately froze and crashed. In some cases the system itself crashed (by "crash" I mean that everything just stops, mouse doesn't move, ctrl+alt+delete doesn't work, etc., sometimes with a terrible hovering sound, I have to disconnect headphones) and sometimes the blue screen pops out. The same situation with browsers, immediately pops out a blue screen when opening (with an error MACHINE_CHECK or something like that).

So I went back to the bios. The first thing I did was to look at the processor settings and saw that Intel Turbo Boost is enabled by default (it's Auto, but it's implied that it's Enabled and it's the default value to which the parameter is reset), I decided to turn it off for the test and oh wonder: all games (and programs) start and work in normal mode with the declared performance, though with the processor artificially slowed down.

Maybe I need to set some settings to make this function work? There is no particularly useful information on Intel's official forums, except for: "try rebooting your computer", etc. I don't really want to live with the feeling that I'm not getting something.

Notes:

- I noticed that with Intel Turbo Boost enabled, Minecraft runs great, no crashes or blue screens for 2+ hours of play, maybe it has something to do with the fact that it's a single-threaded game
- Temperature in games without Intel Turbo Boost: 45-60 °C (depends on the game)

Comment: This is a Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).